# How can I make Jeditable use the Bootstrap button classes for Ok/Cancel?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jeditable

I know that I can style the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons created by Jeditable with a css file like this:

```
form.editable > button {
color : #F00
}
```

I want Jeditable to use the existing Bootstrap classes `btn btn-danger` and `btn btn-success`.

I know I can just copy and paste the CSS from bootstrap into my custom css file but this seems disgusting.

What is the proper way to do this? I have googled around without much success and read the jeditable docs, but the solution is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just got interested in this and I found out that it is as simple as this :)

```js
$('.edit_area').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
     type: 'textarea',
     cancel: '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="cancel" >Cancel</button>',
     submit: '<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" >Ok</button>'
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/master/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>

<div class="edit_area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae officiis reprehenderit tempora rerum quaerat sed totam recusandae sint doloremque perspiciatis omnis illum facilis odio perferendis quibusdam sequi ab consectetur repudiandae.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit the Bootstrap CSS customize page: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
2. Click 'Toggle All' and select only 'Buttons'
3. Click Compile and Download
4. Open the zip file and load the `bootstrap-theme.css` file into your app
5. Add the `btn` classes your buttons: `<button class="button btn btn-success" type="submit" >Ok</button>`

This will give you just the Bootstrap you need (not the entire CSS library) and allow you to style your buttons as Bootstrap buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
$.fn.editableform.buttons = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info editable-submit">'+
'<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></button>'+
'<button type="button" class="btn editable-cancel"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>';
```